# How to specify data type of elements in array which is based on a class?

Tags: java

I need to create an instance variable called ocean, using the data type Coordinate[][]

Where do I specify that the data type of the elements in the array should be type char?

As per the instructions, I can't add input parameters to the constructor in the Coordinate class.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
package battleshipmodel;

// Player class contains a default implementation for a player.
// This class could represent a simple human or artificial player.
public class Player {

    // Your implementation goes here.
    // Instance variables.
    final static int OCEAN_SIZE = 10;
    final static int FLEET_SIZE = 5;
    public static Coordinate[][] ocean;


    // Constructor.
    protected Player(String name) {
//        this.OCEAN_SIZE = 10;
//        this.FLEET_SIZE;
        this.ocean = new Coordinate[OCEAN_SIZE][OCEAN_SIZE];

    // Method getOcean(): Accessor method.
    public static Coordinate[][] getOcean() {
        return ocean;
    }


    public static void printOcean() {//Coordinate.showShips) {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println("  +");

            for (int j = 0; j < OCEAN_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
                  System.out.print("---+");
            }
            System.out.println(i + "  ");
            for (int j = 0; j < OCEAN_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
                  Coordinate coordinate = ocean[i][j];
                  System.out.print(coordinate.printCoordinate(true));
            }
        }
    }
}

=========== Coordinate Class =======================

package battleshipmodel;

// Class Coordinate contains all implementation for one coordinate of the ocean
// for any player. Can be references when dealing with a player's ocean or
// the opponent's "target" ocean.
public class Coordinate {

    // Your implementation goes here.

    // Instance variables.
    final String HIT;
    final String MISS;
    final String EMPTY;
    final String UNKNOWN;
    public Ship ship;
    public boolean isHit;

    // Constructor.
    protected Coordinate() {
        this.HIT = "X";
        this.MISS = "-";
        this.EMPTY = " ";
        this.UNKNOWN = " ";
        this.ship = null;
        this.isHit = false;
    }

    // Method setShip(): Mutator method.
    public void setShip(Ship ship) {
        this.ship = ship;
    }

    // Method hasShip(): Checks if ship at coordinates.
    // Returns TRUE if ship at coordinate.
    protected static boolean hasShip() {
//        Coordinate ocean[][] = Player.getOcean();
//        return ocean[][] == this.EMPTY;
        return false;
    }   

}
```

Comment: So this is homework? What other restrictions do you have and what has characters got to do with the `Coordinate` class, it has no such instance variables? If you want to use chars for indexes in some coordinate system in your array why not use numbers instead, 0 = 'a', 1 = 'b', ...

Comment: Yeah it is. The array is supposed to be storing characters. This works: 
`char[] ocean = new char[3]; 
ocean[2] = 'c'; 
System.out.println(beach[2]);` 

but I can't figure out where to specify the "char[]" part of it in either of the classes. 
If I'm understanding it correctly, the main restrictions are in what data types can be used.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You have an array ocean, should it be Coordinate[][] or char[] or...?

Comment: It should be Coordinate[][], but I'm confused about where/how I specify what the data type of the elements should be.

Comment: They should of course be of type `Coordinate`, that is what you have declared.

Comment: Yeah, but then do I need to declare the type of Coordinate?

Comment: `Coordinate` _is_ the type and you need to fill your array by creating a new instance , `new Coordinate();` for each index in your array.

Comment: it's giving the error "constructor Coordinate in class Coordinate cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: char reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length". 
Part of the assignment restrictions, are that the Coordinate constructor, has no input parameters.

Comment: Then don't send any arguments like I did in my example. I still don't understand why you insist with your char.

Comment: How do I specify what the Coordinates should be then?

Comment: Am also getting the error "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to Coordinate" when trying to assign `ocean[j][yCoordinate] = new Coordinate();

                ocean[j][yCoordinate] = initial;`